# Setting Environment variable in Linux

Tags: java, linux, maven, environment-variables

I am using Maven for my project and I need to set environment variables in my system for it to work. I have set environment variable for maven but it also requires setting up Java environment variable. I am accessing linux through Putty through a remote server. I tried setting up JAVA_HOME environment variable but I get this error:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.We cannot execute /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/jre/bin/java

I used export `JAVA_HOME=/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/jre` for this purpose

Even when i try to execute the java.exe file directlty in linux I get error

> -bash: ./java.exe: cannot execute binary file

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: where does that jre come from?  A linux executable won't have an .exe extension typically, and the Oracle or OpenJDK supplied java executable definitely doesn't have an .exe extension.  Did you by any chance copy over that file from a Windows system?

Comment: Yes, since I am working on windows and accessing linux through Putty. I copied the file from windows to my remote folder. I do not have access to download maven directly from command line.

Comment: Try downloading for linux then :D

Comment: Downloaded for linux. Getting this error: cannot execute binary file.  `mvn -version
/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: line 190: /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
/home/z222189/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn: line 190: /home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31/bin/java: Success`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't refer to the `jre/` subfolder, as Maven will need a Java compiler and potentially other JDK-only tools.

So just use:

```
 JAVA_HOME=/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31
```

EDIT: (making sure that a *correct*, *working* JDK is installed at that location, of course...)

Comment: Even that results in the same thing. I tried that too.

Comment: Perhaps you should make sure your java, and like @fvu says, make sure it's not a Windows installation on a Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are in `Linux`, be sure you **get Java for Linux**!

Set `JAVA_HOME` using

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/z222189/jdk1.8.0_31
```

Does not work because java is not there, or the version is not the correct, if you already installed correct java linux version and you dont really know where your `oracle-java` is installed, you can find this running

```
which java
```

which will tell you which binary of `java` is being called, normally is something like

```
/usr/bin/java
```

but you can

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/java
```

that will give you something like

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

ergo

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/
```